# How to set state based on different functions in react using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios, state

I am trying to make a template system in my survey tool and set the state to a json object which will be pushed onto the firebase database, but I want to know how to change the state based on which template i choose in the previous page:

I have 4 templates:

- Blank
- Board
- Board Member
- Chairperson

I am showing these as buttons and when any of them is clicked the corresponding handlers run

```
<button
        onClick={function(event) {
          props.clicked();
          notify();
        }}
        className={classes.Blank}
      >
        Blank Survey
      </button>
      <button onClick={props.board} className={classes.Board}>
        Board Survey
      </button>
      <button onClick={props.chair} className={classes.Chair}>
        Chairperson Survey
      </button>
      <button onClick={props.member} className={classes.Member}>
        Board Member Survey
      </button>
```

Now I use the props to assign them to corresponding handlers:

```
<NewSurveyView
      clicked={this.clickHandler}
      board={this.boardHandler}
      chair={this.chairHandler}
      member={this.memberHandler}
      isLoading={this.props.loading}
      error={this.props.isError}
    />
```

These are the three functions I am using to fetch the templates:

```
const fetchBoardMember = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "/surveys/ckb0kmt3n000e3g5rmjnfw4go/content/questions.json"
  );
  return res.data;
};

const fetchBoard = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "/surveys/ckb24goc800013g5r7j8igrk3/content/questions.json"
  );
  return res.data;
};

const fetchChair = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "/surveys/ckb24gt3s00053g5rrf60353r/content/questions.json"
  );
  return res.data;
};
```

Next, I create an object with all the info which i want to push (this is for Board Template):

```
const board = {
  title: "Your Survey Title",
  subTitle: "Your Survey Description",
  creatorDate: new Date(),
  lastModified: new Date(),
  questions: fetchBoard().then(questions => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      content: {
        ...state.content,
        questions
      }
    }));
  }),
  submitting: true
};
```

Setting the state:

```
this.setState({
  _id: newId(),
  content: board,
  userId: this.props.user_Id
});
```

Now my question is, how do I change the variable used based on the template chosen by using the buttons?

Comment: Why are you setting the state twice, both separately and inside the board object?

Comment: @edison16029 I am setting it twice because the first time I am getting the question template and updating that to the questions key, while the second time is to make the final object to be pushed

Comment: So where do you call the second part "Setting the state" ?

Comment: @edison16029 I am calling it in the componentDidMount() function